# Comparing dates in Swift ignoring current timezone

Tags: swift

In Swift I can find the difference between two dates using `Calendar.current.dateComponents`

The problem is that this gives the difference relative to my current time zone.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm XXX"

let from = zoneFormatter.date(from: "2018-03-25 00:00 +00:00")!
let to = zoneFormatter.date(from: "2018-03-26 00:00 +00:00")!

let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: from, to: to)
// components is 1 day, 1 hour, because I am in UK and Daylight Savings started on 25 March.
```

How can I retrieve the absolute difference between the two instants specified in the same format which `dateComponents` returns?

Comment: try to use the middle of the day (and also the correct format `ZZZZ`) if possible. Like "2018-03-25 12:00 +00:00". This works for me, but I did not investigate why "00:00" does not work yet. I guess it is about how the time "00:00" is interpreted. "2018-03-25 23:59:59 +0000" does work as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Incorrect Date Format String**

Looks like your using the incorrect format for your dates. The date format for the specified date of `"2018-03-25 00:00 +00:00"` is actually `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm ZZZZZ"`. Give that format a try and it should fix the problem.

*Why does the incorrect format not work for comparison between  time zones?*

This is because it was the timeZone component of your format string that is incorrect. This means the timeZone will not be accounted for in the comparison.

Comment: I still get 1 day 1 hour. I am looking for a comparison ignoring current timezone, i.e. 1 day 0 hour.

Answer (score -1):

The timezone of `Calendar.current` can be changed by setting the system default timezone as follows:

```
NSTimeZone.default = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")! as TimeZone
```